# Odoo 16 one2many treeview not full size of <group>

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-16

I want to show multiple one2may treeviews in a form view. 
The problem is that the treeviews will not show the full size of the group, but the header of the group is shown correctly.

Here is the code:

```
<notebook>
                    <page string="Planing">
                      
                      <group col="2">
                        
                        <group string="Timesheet">
                                
                              
                               
                                
                                    <field name="timesheet_ids" widget="one2many" nolabel="1">;
                                        <tree editable="bottom">
                                            <field name="time_event_type"/>
                                            <field name="date"/>
                                            <field name="begin_time" widget="float_time"/>
                                            <field name="end_time" widget="float_time"/>
                                            <field name="total_hours" widget="float_time" readonly="true"/>
                                        </tree>
                                    </field>
                                </group>
                        
                          
                          
                            <group string="Daily Allowance">

                                  
                                    <field name="planned_daily_allowance_ids" nolabel="1">
                                        <tree editable="bottom">
                                            <field name="daily_allowance"/>
                                            <field name="da_description"/>
                                            <field name="daily_allowance_amount"/>
                                            <field name="number_of_days"/>
                                            <field name="number_of_employee"/>
                                            <field name="correct_number_of_employee"/>
                                            <field name="line_total"/>
                                            <field name="event_master_id"/>

                                        </tree>
                                    </field>
                            </group>


                     </group>

                      
                     </page>

#More Pages
</notebook>
```

Here you can see the view in the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tpmn.png)

I have tried all kinds of col values and testets with colspan.
But no change fixed it. 
Does someone have an idea for a solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `colspan="2"` on the field tag

Groups define 2 columns and most direct children of groups take a single column.

The number of columns in a `group` can be customized using the `col` attribute, the number of columns taken by an element can be customized using `colspan`.

You can find more details in the [Structural components](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#structural-components) documentation section